# Java variable not used

Tags: java

I've written below piece of code. In eclipse, it keeps cribbing that callPremiumTo is not used. Also, when I test my application, I don't get proper value. I'm not able to figure out where the bug is.

```
Double callPremiumFrom = null;
Double callPremiumTo = null;
try {
  callPremiumFrom = (Double) callPremiumFromComboBox.getSelectedItem();
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
  // ignore
}
try {
  callPremiumTo = (Double) callPremiumToComboBox.getSelectedItem();
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
  // ignore
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're setting it to a value but not using that value afterwards...

Comment: Is it required to use a value that is set ? I thought it is only required to set a value that is declared.

Answer (score 5):

The warning that Eclipse is showing is because you're writing to `callPremiumTo` but never reading from it.  Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to tell what "Also, when I test my application, I don't get proper value" means.

Comment: hes not reading from `callPremiumTo` any less than hes reading from `callPremiumFrom` so why does he only get a warning only for `callPremiumTo`?

Comment: @MrD My guess is that he's either reading from `callPremiumFrom` in a line of code not posted, or he is getting the same warning and didn't notice it.

Comment: @TechCrunch input please

Comment: I did a wrong variable assignment at other place, which I forgot now. I fixed it. But what I felt was since there is only object in heap, both of them might be using same memory and so I would have got this unused variable error. I may be completely wrong. But I am very confident that it is not because of not reading the variable.

Comment: @MrD, yes I think I was reading from callPremiumFrom from a line not posted. But my question is, I'm setting the value right ? Is n't that sufficient as using the variable ?

Comment: @TechCrunch No, that's not enough to suppress the warning.  Setting the value is meaningless if you never read it.  You could leave the value null or 0 and it wouldn't matter if no part of your program ever reads the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is telling you that you assigned a value to a variable but you never used that variable anywhere else to read its value, at least not anywhere else besides this assignment. In other words, you never used the variable, so you might just as well remove it from your code. That is warning, not an compiler error.

Comment: It is not because of not reading that value. Then why is the error not seen for callPremiumFrom ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error finally. There was wrong initialization at another place. Since Double is an object, both are pointing to same memory and hence this variable is not used.

Comment: That's simply not true. The **warning** (not error) is displayed when the variable is never read. You only assigned to it but never used it.

Comment: But you can clear see from the snippet that I'm using it right ?